# if $(m,133)=1 ,(n,133)=1$ and,$m,n \in \Bbb Z$ then $133|m^{18} -n^{18}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how to prove if $(m,133)=1 ,(n,133)=1$ and,$m,n \in \Bbb Z$ then $133|m^{18} -n^{18}$
Can you please point in me the correct direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does (m,133) = 1 mean ? Can you please clarify ? And does the operation in $133|m^18 - n^18$ mean division ?

Comment: It almost surely means divides.

Comment: $(a,b)=d$ used to be (and still is) standard notation for $\gcd(a,b)=d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$133=7\times19$

$U(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_{133})\cong U(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_7)\oplus U(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_{19})\cong\mathbb{Z}_6\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{18}$. Let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}_6\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{18}$. It follws easily that the order of $(a,b)$ is $lcm(6,18)=18$. Thus, for every $n$ coprime with $133$, we have $133|n^{18}-1$

---

Another way that makes use of FLT only:

Let $n$ be coprime with $133$. Thus, $n$ is coprime with $7,19$. By FLT, $n^6\equiv 1\pmod 7$, therefore $n^{18}\equiv 1^3\equiv 1\pmod 7$. Thus, $7|(n^{18}-1)$. Using FLT, we know that $19|n^{18}-1$. Since $7,19$ are coprime, therefore $133|n^{18}-1$